# How to clear notifications when the app is running?

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

My app creates a notification in my Service class depending on the data in the FirebaseDatabase. What I want to accomplish is to clear the notification that is created when the app opens. The notification clears itself if I click on the notification itself but I want it to also clear when app is opened through other ways. Also when I add data to my database it creates a notification even though if the app is running. Is there a way to disable that?

This is my Service

```
public class Service extends android.app.Service {

public DatabaseReference databaseReference, PantryReference, RefReference;
public ChildEventListener childEventListener, childEventListener1, childEventListener2;
public Date dateFormat;
public String mContentTitle = "NotifTest", mContentText;
private static final int uniqueID = 57891258;
public NotificationCompat.Builder notification;
private boolean mRunning;

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mRunning = false;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    //---------------------- Check if its already running
    if (!mRunning){
        mRunning = true;

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------- Since Service cannot get groupUid in static from MainActivity
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("GroupUid", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String mGroupUid = sharedPreferences.getString("GroupUid", groupUid);

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Setting up Notification FreezerItems
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Groups").child(mGroupUid).child("HomeFragment").child("1");
        childEventListener = databaseReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            HashMap<String, String> value = (HashMap<String, String>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
            if (value != null) {
                String name = value.get("name");
                String date = value.get("date");


                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("M/dd/yyyy", Locale.US);

                try {
                    dateFormat = sdf.parse(date);

                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                //------------------------------------------ setting the dates
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                cal.setTime(dateFormat);
                String mDate = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
                cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
                String yesterday = sdf.format(cal.getTime());


                if (TodayDate.equals(yesterday)) {

                    mContentText =  name;
                    NotificationCreate(mContentText);

                } else if (TodayDate.equals(mDate)){

                    mContentText = name;
                    NotificationCreate(mContentText);
                }


            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}


 private void createNotificationChannel(Context context) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        CharSequence name = "ChannelName";
        String description = "FoodExpiration";
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("Default", name, importance);
        channel.setDescription(description);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = context.getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        if (notificationManager != null) {
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to clear notification bellow you can use it in your case where you need, Just you need to remember you notification id which you defining for clear specific notification otherwise you can clear all.

**Specific notification**

```
public void clearNotofication(int notificationId) {
        String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
        NotificationManager nMgr = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(ns);
        nMgr.cancel(notificationId);
    }
```

**Cancel All**

just replace  `nMgr.cancel(notificationId);` to `nMgr.cancelAll();` from Above code.

Answer (score 0):

For clearing single Notificaion:

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
```

And for clearing all of notification.

```
notificationManager.cancelAll();
```